# SQL Group with SUM

Tags: sql, count, group-by, sum

Below is the set of data.

```
ID|NAME |AMOUNT|COUNTRY|No. ITEM|
1 |ARIES|23.00 |US     |2
2 |ARIES|13.00 |US     |3
3 |VINCE|22.00 |US     |4
4 |VINCE|32.00 |UK     |5
```

Required output. is this possible in SQL command?
to count number of record for US and NON USA and Sum the No. of ITEM for US and NON-USA.

```
NAME |AMOUNT|US Count|NON US COUNT|US NO. ITEM|NON - US NO. ITEM
ARIES|36.00 |       2|           0|          5|               0
VINCE|22.00 |       1|           0|          4|               0
VINCE|32.00 |       0|           1|          4|               5
```

Comment: Shouldn't the last row be  VINCE 32 0 1 0 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT NAME,
       SUM(AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT,
       SUM(CASE WHEN COUNTRY = 'US' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS US_COUNT,
       SUM(CASE WHEN COUNTRY = 'US' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS NON_US_COUNT,
       SUM(CASE WHEN COUNTRY = 'US' THEN [No. ITEM] ELSE 0 END) AS US_NO_ITEM,
       SUM(CASE WHEN COUNTRY = 'US' THEN 0 ELSE [No. ITEM] END) AS NON_US_NO_ITEM
FROM   Table
GROUP BY NAME,
       COUNTRY
```

Comment: @techdo I don't think so... If the country is 'US' then the case is 1 else it is 0. If you SUM all the 1s then you will get an effective COUNT of all US. Same goes for non US.

Comment: In his answer, ARIES (2), VINCE (1) and VINCE(1). But as per your query, it's showing 2, 1, 0. Please check.

Comment: @techdo I think his example is wrong. Can you see based on his data how Vince has 32 and US 1? In the example US NO ITEM is wrong too in the last row.

Comment: @jyparask I changed the result yest VINCE should be 0 for US.

Comment: @user2617053 Does my solution suit your need?

Comment: @jyparsk the US Count|NON US COUNT|US NO. ITEM|NON - US NO. ITEM have the same output

Comment: @user2617053 I don't quite understand what you mean. Check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/aab8e/3 it has the correct output.